# Oracle XML version

Tags: xml, oracle, prestashop

Is it possible to work with XML in oracle so that it does not convert empty nodes?

I have XML files:

```
<foo></foo>
```

If I convert from clob to XMLTYPE and then do some operations (e.g. updatexml) the file will be converted and empty nodes will be saved like this: `<foo/>`

And this format is not supported by PrestaShop...